# Error variable de objeto para señalar una tabla VBA

Tags: vba

Buenas tardes estimados,

tengo el siguiente botón de guardar que registra información desde un formulario, sin embargo al iniciar el primer registro me arroja error :
se ha producido el error 91 variable de objeto o bloque with no establecido y señala lo resaltado:

Despues funciona correctamente cuando ya hay valores insertado el problema es solo para el primer registro.
Por favor si me podrían ayudar a solucionar el error.

Muchas gracias.

```
 Private Sub cmdguardar_Click()

 Dim nombres As Variant
 Dim dnis As Variant
 Dim uFT, uF1 As Long
 Dim Celda As Range
 Dim i%
 Dim fila As ListRow
 Dim tabla As ListObject

 'Declaramos la tabla
 Set tabla = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabla2")

 'Definimos las matrizes de los nombres y dni
 nombres = Split(txtcol, vbCrLf)

 dnis = Split(txtdni, vbCrLf)

 'Recorremos para cada nombre (si solo hay 1, no importa, solo hará un 
  ciclo)

  For i = 0 To UBound(nombres)

 'Última fila de la tabla

uFT = tabla.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Pasamos los datos a la tabla

 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1) = Val(Txtn)  ---> LINEA ERROR
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1).Offset(0, 1) = cboregimen
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1).Offset(0, 2) = CDate(txtfecha)
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1).Offset(0, 3) = cbounidad
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1).Offset(0, 4) = nombres(i)
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1).Offset(0, 5) = dnis(i)
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1).Offset(0, 6) = cbocargo
 tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1).Offset(0, 7) = txtjornal

'Aumentamos el contador del Nº
Txtn = Txtn + 1

Next i

 'Vaciamos los 2 textbox

 txtcol = ""
 txtdni = ""

 'Vaciamos las matrizes

 Erase nombres
 Erase dnis

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dices que tu código falla en la primera pasada *("...sin embargo al iniciar el primer registro me arroja error : se ha producido el error 91 variable de objeto o bloque with no establecido...")*

También dices que si hay registros, tu código no falla *("...Despues funciona correctamente cuando ya hay valores insertado el problema es solo para el primer registro...")*

Esta información me hace pensar que **tu tabla está vacía al inicio del código**, es decir, **solamente los encabezados**. Al no tener información, cuando se ejecuta el código, en la primera pasada sucede lo siguiente:

```
 'Última fila de la tabla

uFT = tabla.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).
```

En la primera pasada, **uFT será igual 1**, porque no hay datos. Te está cogiendo la fila donde tienes el encabezado. Entonces el código al llegar a la línea:

```
tabla.DataBodyRange.Cells(uFT, 1) = Val(Txtn)  '---> LINEA ERROR
```

**Está intentado modificar la celda (1,1), que es el propio encabezado**. Por eso te da error.

Para arreglarlo, es fácil. Simplemente tienes que conseguir que la primera celda de la columna 1 (columna 1 porque según tu código es donde ejecutas el Find, `tabla.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find`) **no sea una celda en blanco**.

Escribe cualquier cosa en ella, porque luego con el código la vas a sobreescribir.

Imaginemos que esa primera celda sea la A2 (y los encabezados de la tabla están en la fila 1). Pues para solucionarlo, justo antes del bucle For, escribe:

```
Range("A2").Value ="Cualquier cosa".'<- Para evitar que falle con el primer registro al estar la tabla vacía

'Recorremos para cada nombre (si solo hay 1, no importa, solo hará un ciclo)

For i = 0 To UBound(nombres)
```

De esta manera, tu variable uFT te devolverá el número de fila que necesitas, y no te fallará al introducir el registro.

Espero que esto ayude.